# How to run test case marked `@unittest.skip` in Python?

Tags: python, python-unittest

Assuming the following test suite:

```py
# test_module.py
import unittest

class Tests(unittest.TestCase):

  @unittest.skip
  def test_1(self):
    print("This should run only if explicitly asked to but not by default")

  # assume many other test cases and methods with or without the skip marker
```

When invoking the unittest library via `python -m unittest` are there any arguments I can pass to it actually run and not skip `Tests.test_1` without modifying the test code and running any other skipped tests?

`python -m unittest test_module.Tests.test_1` correctly selects this as the only test to run, but it still skips it.

If there is no way to do it without modifying the test code, what is the most idiomatic change I can make to conditionally undo the `@unittest.skip` and run one specific test case test case?

In all cases, I still want `python -m unittest discover` (or any other invocation that doesn't explicitly turn on the test) to skip the test.

Comment: The question is why are these tests skipped in the first place? Usually skipping a test involves some condition in which case it makes no sense to run the test anyway because the required resources might not be available. Unconditionally skipping a test makes only sense if you remove the skip some time in the future, so that involves source code modification anyway. Otherwise you could just remove the test from the suite completely.

Comment: Thank you @a_guest. These are long-running tests that could be run any time but they are off by default because of the time they take. I want to manually execute some of them (but not all at the same time).

Comment: Another case is a running test I expect to fail because of a bug in the system under test. But I might want to run it anyway to see if a change in the code fixed it to see if the skip decorator can be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to skip some expensive tests you can use a [conditional skip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.skipIf) together with a custom [environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv):

```
@skipIf(int(os.getenv('TEST_LEVEL', 0)) < 1)
def expensive_test(self):
    ...
```

Then you can include this test by specifying the corresponding environment variable:

```
TEST_LEVEL=1 python -m unittest discover
TEST_LEVEL=1 python -m unittest test_module.Tests.test_1
```

If you want to skip a test because you expect it to fail, you can use the dedicated [`expectedFailure`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.expectedFailure) decorator.

By the way, `pytest` has a dedicated decorator for [marking slow tests](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#control-skipping-of-tests-according-to-command-line-option).

Comment: Thank you! This almost works for me, but this seems to imply that I either define a separate environment variable for each test method or otherwise `TEST_LEVEL=1 python -m unittest discover` will run all my tests instead of the one I want.

Comment: You can combine this with [pattern matching](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#cmdoption-unittest-k) of test methods, so `TEST_LEVEL=1` just means activate expensive tests and then what tests you will run depends on the pattern you specify.

Comment: I edited the answer to add this. Accepted and thanks!

Comment: Sadly, not applicable for tests that I have no control on the source. For example, on exercism.org, a student can download and work on the exercises locally, but any change to test files are ignored upon submission. It'd really be useful to have a command line flag that I could set when running locally, such as `--include-skipped`.